# Are mult-adds and FLOPs equivalent?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, terminology, papers, complexity-theory

I am comparing different CNN architectures for edge implementation. Some papers describing architectures refer to *mult-adds*, like [the MobileNet V1 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04861.pdf), where it is claimed that this net has 569M mult-adds, and others refer to floating-point operations (FLOPs), like [the CondenseNet paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.09224.pdf) claims 274M FLOPs.

Are these comparable? Is 1 multiply-add equivalent to 2 floating-point operations? Any direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes if I have to take a guess. The clue is in the name...multiply with weights and add. Although it should be more flops since there are many multiplication in a single neuron input.

Comment: One of [the papers that you mention](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.09224.pdf) states "_Throughout the paper, FLOPs refers to the number of multiplication-addition operations_", and this is consistent with my knowledge of FLOPS, which are pretty standard in computational science (i.e. analysis and implementation of numerical algorithms, etc.). However, it is the first time I hear of "mult-add", to be honest, so I would need to check what those papers actually refer to when they calculate the "mult-adds".

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51082939/3924118) says they are equivalent, but it doesn't explain why. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51866343/3924118) seems to provide more insight. Maybe later I will provide a more formal answer.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this source](https://github.com/sovrasov/flops-counter.pytorch/issues/16), one MAC is roughly equal to two FLOP (multiply accumulate). My guess/understanding would be that the distinction is made because neural nets spend compute overwhelmingly on multiply-accumulate operations, and thus optimizations and statistics over MAC operations would be more significant than FLOPs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130233/discussion-on-answer-by-k-c-sayz-k-c-sayz-are-mult-adds-and-flops-equivalent).